# dynamic configuration of states using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router to generate multiple states, views and subviews. it looks like below :

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
        url : "/dashboard",
        controller : function($scope,  $filter) {
            console.log($scope, '$scope');*/
        views : {
            "header":{
                templateUrl : getTemplate("dashboardHeader"),
                controller : function($scope,  $filter) {
                    console.log($scope.location, '$scope');
                }
            },
            "body" : {
                templateUrl : getTemplate("dashboardChart"),
                controller : function($scope,  $filter) {
                    console.log($scope, '$scope');
                }
            }
        }
    }).state('dashboard.insight', {
        url : "/:insight",
        templateUrl : getTemplate("insight"),
        controller : function($scope,  $filter) {
            console.log($scope, 'Sameer Test');
        }
    }).state('products', {
        url : "/products",
        views: {
            "header":{
                templateUrl: getTemplate("productHeader"),
                controller: function($scope, Restangular, $filter, PlatformService){
                    .......
                }
            },
            "body":{
                templateUrl:getTemplate("products"),
                controller : function($scope, Restangular, $filter, $route, $routeParams, $location, ngDialog,PlatformService) {
                        .......
                    } );
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

here dashboard and products are main views. insight is dynamically binded using ui-sref. i want to move all these a JSON structure so that i can configure which client needs which all states views and controllers. like some may need dashboard some may not.

So i decided to use app.run() to load these configurations. But i am not getting subviews of dashboard and states which are "dashboard.insight" (/:insight). As JSON will have dashboard not dashboard.insight.

How to achieve this.

Comment: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future here is one way. View the demo page source code on GitHub.